# Then why $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

The problem originates from here:http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0002989019147.di991715.99p14142.pdf

> Let $\lambda (t)$ be a non-constant, periodic function with bounded derivative, and define

$$f(x)=\int ^x_0[\lambda'(t)]^2dt.$$

Then why is

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

Comment: Because the integral of the nonnegative function $(\lambda')^2$ over one period is strictly positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lambda$ is non-constant, and $\lambda'(t)$ cannot have average value $0$ around almost every point by Lebesgue differentiation and non-constantness of $\lambda$. So $\exists a<b\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$0<c={1\over b-a}\int_a^b|\lambda'(t)|^2\,dt$$

on $[a,b]$. Let $T>|b-a|$ be a period for $\lambda$ and hence for $\lambda'$. Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{a+nT}^{b+nT}|\lambda'(t)|^2\,dt<\int_{\Bbb R} |\lambda'(t)|^2\,dt$$

so that the integral is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be a period of $f$. Then $\lambda(t)'$ is a periodic function, non equal to 0.

So $\int_0^{nT} \lambda(t)'^2 dt = n\int_0^{T} \lambda(t)'^2 dt = nI $ with
$$
I = \int_0^{T} \lambda(t)'^2 dt > 0
$$and, as $\lambda(t)'^2>0$, with
$$
x-1 < n_xT \le x:\\
\int_0^x \lambda(t)'^2 dt \ge n_xI \to_{x\to\infty}\infty
$$